# Как использовать полученные данные в другом activity?

Tags: android, activity, recyclerview, android-intent

У меня есть recyclerview в который я передаю данные с сервера с помощью JSON. С recyclerview проблем нет.

Проблема заключается в том что я не могу понять как использовать те же данные для того же элемента при переходе на другое activity.

Вот код моего recyclerview adapter

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.places_list, parent,false);
    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
    Places current=placesList.get(position);
    myHolder.cardName.setText(current.name);
    myHolder.cardAbout.setText(current.about);
    Glide.with(context).load(current.image)
            .into(myHolder.cardImage);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,PlaceActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            intent.putExtra("places", (Serializable) placesList);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
        }
    });

}
```

Вот код activity куда я хочу перекинуть данные

```
public class PlaceActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {
Places p;
List<Places> plist;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place);
    int position;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int current = extras.getInt("position");
        List<Places> Places = (List<Places>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("places");
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        p = Places.get(current);
        int s = current;
        Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Toast создал чтобы протестировать, но ничего не получается...

Вот что выдает при попытке поменять местами putExtra и startActivity

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.admin.friday, PID: 5731
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.example.admin.friday.Places@f32677d
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1397)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:738)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665)
                  at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
                  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690)
                  at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7793)
                  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2639)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1507)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:720)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
                  at com.example.admin.friday.PlaceAdapter$1.onClick(PlaceAdapter.java:79)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Сначала `putExtra`, потом `startActivity` - должно помочь.

Comment: если меняю startactivity и putExtra то приложение крашится когда захожу на какой-либо элемент

Comment: Слово "крашится" мало информативно - стектрейс ошибки к вопросу приложите.

Comment: Я же тебе говорил, напиши на почту. Ща сделаю маленькое приложение, залью сюда код.

Comment: Places  вот этот класс  реализует интерфейс Serializable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работу с JSON я не расписывал. Но думаю разобраться тебе не составит труда.
Класс модели:

```
public class MyModel {
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String imageUrl;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Разметка модели:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_iv"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_txv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_iv"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_txv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_txv"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_iv"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Класс MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerListener{

    private List<MyModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //находим ресайкл и его составные части и делаем с ними телодвижения
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, this);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        //ручками вставил строковые ресурсы для каждой модели.
        //тут ты уже сам вместо строк вставляй свой JSON
        for(int a=0; a<10; a++) {
            final MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
            myModel.setTitle("Title_"+a);
            myModel.setDescription("Description_"+a);
            myModel.setImageUrl("https://i.mycdn.me/i?r=ADGc-AHOhhk0xU4_G5aVlnAECGRm3fig_cX1pJkGgx7jKyFEKHwKiL9QuGcq4J-B13c");
            list.add(myModel);
        }
        myAdapter.updateData(list);
    }

    //реализовываем метод интерфейса для перехода в
    // 2 активити с ключами модельки по которой кликнул
    @Override
    public void openSecondActivity(final MyModel myModel) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("titleIntent", myModel.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("descriptionIntent", myModel.getDescription());
        intent.putExtra("imageUrlIntent", myModel.getImageUrl());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Класс адаптера для ресайкла

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<MyModel> list;
    private Context context;
    private RecyclerListener recyclerListener;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, RecyclerListener recyclerListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.recyclerListener = recyclerListener;
    }

    public void updateData(List<MyModel> list) {
        this.list = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)  {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_my_model,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final MyModel myModel = list.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(myModel.getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(myModel.getDescription());
        Glide.with(context).load(myModel.getImageUrl()).into(holder.image);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recyclerListener.openSecondActivity(myModel);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list != null) {
            return list.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private ImageView image;
        private TextView title;
        private TextView description;

        MyViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            this.image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_iv);
            this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_txv);
            this.description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_txv);
        }
    }
}
```

Разметка activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Класс другой активити

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView title;
    private TextView description;
    private ImageView image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        //находим элементы экрана
        title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_txv);
        description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.description_txv);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_iv);

        //берем ключи которые передали из 1 активити
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String titleIntent= intent.getStringExtra("titleIntent");
        String descriptionIntent= intent.getStringExtra("descriptionIntent");
        String imageUrlIntent= intent.getStringExtra("imageUrlIntent");

        //вставляем ключи в разметку
        title.setText(titleIntent);
        description.setText(descriptionIntent);
        Glide.with(this).load(imageUrlIntent).into(image);
    }
}
```

Разметка другой активити

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_iv"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_txv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/image_iv"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description_txv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_txv"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/image_iv"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Интерфейс:

```
public interface RecyclerListener{
void openSecondActivity(final Mymodel mymodel);
}
```